# Are parentheses ignored when assigning JSX to a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx, variable-assignment

I'm learning about the javascript basics. The two lines of code seem equivalent and I'm wondering if the parser simply ignores the parentheses in the second case:

```
var a = 5 + 5;
```

```
var b = (5 + 5);
```

EDIT:
I realize the context of the question might of help after going through the comments, which are helpful. I was trying to assign some JSX to a variable and noticed that the parentheses seem optional:

```
var a = 
  <div>
    <SomeComponent />
  </div>;
```

```
var b = (
  <div>
    <SomeComponent />
  </div>
);
```

In the case of a `return` statement, I understand that parentheses are needed due to automatic semicolon injection. But in case of a simple assignment do the parentheses still matter?

EDIT 2:
Thanks for the comments and answer that help me narrow down and articulate my question. I think what I really meant to ask is, does JSX parser (e.g. Babel) ignore the parentheses in such a case? Since both will be transpiled into:

```
var a = React.createElement(
  "div",
  null, 
  React.createElement(
    SomeComponent, 
    null
  )
)
```

Comment: They are not ignored. They are parsed. They have no impact on semantics in the code above. Consider `var c = 5 + 5 * 3;` compared to `var d = (5 + 5) * 3;`

Comment: The parser certainly can't ignore any code, but they become irrelevant at some point if they don't change the execution of the code. If you're wondering if there's some runtime overhead, there's not.

Comment: In this instance you are comparing two of the same things. As @Aluan Haddad mentioned; do you notice a difference if you add another operation?

Comment: Regarding your edit, because white space is *generally* insignificant in JS, when the parser sees `var b = ` with a line break following it, it knows that it has an incomplete declaration, and so will continue onto the next line in order to attempt to complete it. Think of it this way, if it had inserted a `;` after the `=`, it would be creating invalid code, and the ASI system only injects semicolons in places where a valid *(though perhaps unintended)*  result can be achieved.

Comment: ...however, that's not actually JS code, so who knows how their parser behaves. Hope there's a specification.

Comment: In addition to what @slappy said, which is correct, the differences in your JSX sample are aesthetic. People started putting `()` around JSX expressions after a `return` statement because they wished to maintain a certain indentation while avoiding ASI. In the case of an assignment, the ASI is irrelevant, because there is no ASI after `=`, but (some) people became accustomed to it.

Answer (score 4):

They're not ignored, but simple mathematics tells you that:

```
5 + 5 == (5 + 5)
```

If you had a different set of values, it would change - e.g.:

```js
var a = (5 * 5) + 5 * 5;
var b = 5 * (5 + 5) * 5;
var c = 5 * 5 + (5 * 5);
var d = (5 * 5 + 5) * 5;
var e = 5 * (5 + 5 * 5);
var f = (5 * 5 + 5 * 5);

console.log(a); // 50
console.log(b); // 250
console.log(c); // 50
console.log(d); // 150
console.log(e); // 150
console.log(f); // 50
```

It depends on the Order of Operations (aka BODMAS/BIDMAS/BEDMAS etc.)

Comment: added permutations to hit home point, hope you dont mind

Comment: Not a problem, thanks for the added depth @LawrenceCherone!